# Отображение изображений

Tags: java, android, gridview

Что нужно от приложения, чтобы отобразить изображения с сервера,
GridView ?

Где можно посмотреть пример, как это все сделать ?

На сервере есть скрипт, который передает url на изображения через json.
В приложении есть класс, который принимает json url и записывает их в массив.

Как сказать GridView, что бы он отображал изображения по даным ссылкам?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Поместите ImageView в разметку элемента GridView
2. Подключите одну из библиотек для отображения изображений по ссылкам (UIL, Picasso, etc)
3. В адаптере GridView в методе отрисовки элемента с помощью библиотеки из п.2 отобразите изображение.

Comment: Спасибо, но знань у меня немного можете сделать минимальной пример как ет сделать ?

Comment: @user208111, не могу - с GridView ни разу дел не имел. Но, если вы по пунктам выполните все действия (мануалов много в сети) то всё у вас заработатет.